# ElasticSearch: Exact match on Keyword datatype field with array of values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6.5

In ElasticSearch, I have a mapping for an email field and title field as given below:

```
  {
  "person": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
         "email": {
           "type": "keyword",
           "boost": 80
          },
          "title": {
          "type": "text",
           "boost": 70
          }
       }
     }
   }
```

Each person can have more than one email address and title. So, I'm storing the values in arrays.
I use query_string to search for persons with an email address and/or title. Email address needs to match exactly.

I have indexed a document with the following data. Calling `GET person/_search` in Kibana will yield the following document in the result.

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "person",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "101",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "title": """["Actor", "Hero", "Model"]""",
          "email": """["jdepp@hotmail.com", "johnny@hollywood.com", "jdepp@gmail.com", "johnny.depp@yahoo.com"]""",
          "SEARCH_ENTITY": "PERSON"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I add some email search parameter I don't get the document back in the result. Remember email is of type keyword.

Request:

```
GET person/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "SEARCH_ENTITY:PERSON AND (email: (johnny.depp@yahoo.com))"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

But the same kind of query works for title field which is of type text.

Request:

```
GET person/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "SEARCH_ENTITY:PERSON AND (title: ((actor)))"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 20.137747,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "person",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "101",
        "_score": 20.137747,
        "_source": {
           "ID": "101",
           "title": """["Actor", "Hero", "Model"]""",
           "email": """["jdepp@hotmail.com", "johnny@hollywood.com", "jdepp@gmail.com", "johnny.depp@yahoo.com"]"""
         }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I need to do to make this work for email field which is of keyword type?

Note: If I store only one email address without using an array, it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you parse the json array strings in `title` and `email` like so before you index your docs:

```
POST person/_doc/101
{
  "title": [
    "Actor",
    "Hero",
    "Model"
  ],
  "email": [
    "jdepp@hotmail.com",
    "johnny@hollywood.com",
    "jdepp@gmail.com",
    "johnny.depp@yahoo.com"
  ],
  "SEARCH_ENTITY": "PERSON"
}
```

Nothing needs to be changed about the mapping -- just the field values.

Comment: When I retrieve the document from the ElasticSearch I see the title and email fields like this:

"title": """["Actor", "Hero", "Model"]""", "email": """["jdepp@hotmail.com", "johnny@hollywood.com", "jdepp@gmail.com", "johnny.depp@yahoo.com"]"""

It makes me think that the array values are indexed correctly, am I not right?

I don't understand why there are 3 double quotes at the beginning and at the end of the arrays.

Comment: Well that's how you indexed them. The triple quotes are a Kibana convention that improves readability because normally, in a strictly valid JSON, you'd have to escape the quotes like `"[\"Actor\"...`. Long story short, you've indexed strings that should've been arrays of strings.

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the triple quotes.

I'm passing in the values with escaped double quotes and in an array. Still doesn't work.

"[\"Actor\", \"Hero\", \"Model\"]"

Comment: Still not it. Pass it as mentioned in my answer. No leading quotes...

Comment: If I pass the array as you listed in your example it works. But I need to pass JSON body to ElasticSearch using PUT API. Inside the body I'm passing these emails as JSONArray object. In that case, this doesn't work. Looks like ElasticSearch thinks that the entire array is one string value. Any ideas how can I pass the array as JSON? Thanks.

Comment: The above _is_ a valid PUT API request. It creates a doc under the ID 101 in the index called `person`... Again, what you're passing the emails as a JSON **string** that only looks like an array but is not. It's what is called a stringified array.

Comment: I'm using Gson to convert the values to json and I found that it was stringifying the array. So had to pass the values of type Object and then it all went well from there. Thanks for your help. It really helped me get this working.

Comment: Glad to have helped!